# How to iterate over pandas data frame rows while referring to other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

In my code I assign a value to a cell in a data frame, based on another value in the same data frame but in another row.

The code, using a for-loop is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3],'B':[4, 5, 6]})
for i in range(1, df.shape[0]):
    df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i-1, 'B']

Output:
    A   B   C
0   1   4   NaN
1   2   5   4.0
2   3   6   5.0
```

This code gives me the output I want, but the code is rather slow. I read about `df.itterrows` and `df.apply` but I cannot find out how this can work for my code since I refer to other rows. Does anyone know a faster way to iterate over rows, referring to other rows in the pandas data frame?

Comment: Refer [How to Create minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Sjoerd post few lines of you df and expected result

Comment: looks like you're just doing `df['C'] = df['B'].shift()` ..?

Comment: The shift function indeed works very well and is much faster, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this way

```
df.iloc[i]['C'] = df.iloc[i-1]['B']
```

Comment: This does not seem to do anything to my data frame. However, as can be found in the comment of Chris A above,  ```df['C'] = df['B'].shift()``` works well and is much faster than my previous code